# How do you use BLOCK_VISIBILITY_PHP, in hook_block_info, to hide a block?

Tags: blocks

I am user #1; I do have the PHP filter module enabled, but still my block is displaying, when I'd like it to be hidden. Here's my implementation of hook_block_info:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function alerts_block_info() {
    $blocks['get_e_mail_alerts'] = array(
        'info' => t('Get e-mail alerts'),
        'status' => TRUE,
        'region' => 'sidebar_first',
        'weight' => 0,
        'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_PHP,
        'pages' => '<?php global $user; if ($user->uid == 1) { return FALSE; } else { return TRUE; } ?>',
    );
    return $blocks;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try using the English spelling of _"visibility"_. You currently seem to have gone for something a bit more fancy in your array keys ;)

Comment: I would have bet my mortgage that was going to work, but it didn't. I cleared all my caches also?

Comment: Do you know if the PHP code gets ran?

Comment: How can I determine that?

Comment: @user1919784 Quickest way to check - chuck `die("it's running");` in the `pages` var and reload a page with the block on

Comment: I put the die code in. The page loaded, no chnage, but at the bottom of the page all the module code after the die statement was printed. I tried Scott's code snippet: no message was set. Does this mean the php is not being run?

Comment: It must. Visit your block in the UI to make sure everything is set properly

Comment: uninstall and re-enable your module and it will work!

Answer (score 1):

I put this in my php code and it works just right:

```
<?php drupal_set_message("here"); global $user; if ($user->uid == 1) { return 0; } else { return 1; } ?>
```

The drupal_set_message is called and everything.